# Triple nested model not building correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I have an `Organisme` that has many `Servicepoints` and each `Servicepoint` has many `Addresses`. The `Servicepoint` is set to `accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses` so that I can create a service point and at the same time create an Address with it.

My problem is that that, I can't figure out how to create the address that will be linked to the `Servicepoint` and that `Servicepoint` be linked to the `Organisme`. I am creating the `Servicepoint` inside the `show` view of an `Organisme`.

View:

```
<%= form_for([@organisme, @organisme.servicepoints.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :nom %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :nom %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :fax %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :fax %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :courriel %><br>
    <%= f.email_field :courriel %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :telephone %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :telephone %>
  </p>
  <%= f.fields_for :addresses do |address_attributes| %>
    <p>
      <%= address_attributes.label :no_civique %><br>
      <%= address_attributes.text_field :no_civique %><br>

      <%= address_attributes.label :rue %><br>
      <%= address_attributes.text_field :rue %><br>

      <%= address_attributes.label :ville %><br>
      <%= address_attributes.text_field :ville %><br>

      <%= address_attributes.label :province %><br>
      <%= address_attributes.text_field :province %><br>

      <%= address_attributes.label :etat %><br>
      <%= address_attributes.text_field :etat %><br>

      <%= address_attributes.label :code_postal %><br>
      <%= address_attributes.text_field :code_postal %><br>
    </p>
<% end %>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit :Ajouter, class: 'btn btn-info' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

organisme/show

```
def show
 @organisme = Organisme.find(params[:id])
end
```

servicepoint/create

```
def create

  @organisme = Organisme.find(params[:organisme_id])

  @servicepoint = @organisme.servicepoints.create(servicepoint_params)

  redirect_to organisme_path(@organisme)  

end

private
  def servicepoint_params
    params.require(:servicepoint).permit(:nom, :fax, :courriel, :telephone, addresses_attributes: [:id, :no_civique, :rue, :ville, :province, :etat, :code_postal])
end
```

Routes:

```
resources :organismes do
  member { patch :activate }
  member { patch :deactivate }
  resources :addresses
  resources :servicepoints do
    resources :addresses
  end
end
```

My problem right now is that the `Address` input information isn't even showing. I tried having a `@servicepoint` variable and then creating everything with that but the problem with that was that I could not link it to the `Organisme`.

If you need any more information I'll be happy to add anything.

Models:

```
class Organisme < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :addresses
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
   has_many :servicepoints
end

class Servicepoint < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :addresses
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
   belongs_to :organisme
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :organismereferent, optional: true
  belongs_to :organisme, optional: true
  belongs_to :servicepoint, optional: true
end
```

Comment: *Address input information isn't even showing* Do you mean you are unable to see addresses attributes in the form?

Comment: Are you saying that when you show an organisme, you do not see the address part of the form?

Comment: @Pavan Ya in my view I can't see the labels and the text_fields.

Comment: @Syl Yes everything in the `<%= f.fields_for :addresses do |address_attributes| %>` does not appear in the view.

Comment: Please post your models code

Comment: @Pavan I added the models.

Comment: Try changing `<%= f.fields_for :addresses do |address_attributes| %>` to `<%= f.fields_for :addresses, @organisme.addresses.build do |address_attributes| %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build everything in the controller action:

```
<%= form_for([@organisme, @servicepoint]) do |f| %>
...


def show
  @organisme = Organisme.find(params[:organisme_id])
  @servicepoint = @organisme.servicepoints.build
  @servicepoint.addressess.build
end
```

Comment: This is the most direct way of solving your problem, if you want a form for creation purposes only, and without possibilities to create more than one address. It is totally useful if this is used as a create servicepoint that the user is able to edit later from another form to add more addresses.

Comment: @Syl Thanks for the information. And yes I wanted to only allow them to add only one Address when they create a new service point.

Answer (score 0):

In the form you build a servicepoint, so an empty serviceform is shown as an empty form. No adress are shown because there is no address to iterate on. You need to build addresses too.

Be aware that your form will never allow you to edit servicepoint(s), because of the build in the form itself. And to allow the form to show more than one servicepoint, you need to iterate servicepoints somewhere.

Comment: Ya I kinda figured that out but I can't find a way of building the addresses.